# Disabling full control over a file for one of administrators in Win7

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, file-permissions

There are two user accounts on Win7 and both with the Administrator type. Is there some way to disable full control over some file for the second administrator and leave him just the Read & execute permission? So that he would be disabled to change permissions and return the full control over the file and only the first administrator would be able to do it

Answer (score 1):

No you can't,  an admistrator has too many rights to be able to restrict this. The first easiest work around I can think of is the restricted administrator just makes a new account that is also a admistrator and reads the file with that.

Other possible options: installing a windows service that runs as SYSTEM that changes the file permissions to let the restricted user write to it, Resetting the password for the first user and logging in has him.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But if to set the Standard user type for the second account with only the Read & execute permission, is it possible to make the user to be disabled to return the full control over the file? I see that the Standard user still can do it

Comment: Standard users can not create other users. Your only options is make the restricted user not a administrator or just set DENY permissions for the 2nd user and ask them nicely to not remove the permissions and hope that they are honest.

Comment: I meant that I changed the type of the second account from Administrator to Standard user and set DENY for this second account. But if I log in this second "restricted" account I still can unset DENY and set the full control for this second account with the Standard user type

Comment: Check who is the owner of the file

Comment: The owner is the first user with the Administrator type

Comment: Ok, I've figured it out. I CHANGED the second account to Standard user but it was CREATED at the beginning as administrator. Now I recreated Standard user account and everything works as needed